# NSTimer with Touch capability? Any other options

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I am creating my very first iphone app and need help here. My programming background is not C and I am bit lost.

Basically what I want my application to do is to display random bitmaps and let user touch individual bitmap and validate them. The method I used to display the bitmaps is NSTimer with UIImage for the actual bitmaps. So far, it was working fine in displaying the bitmap. But I am stuck on the next step, which is registering the touched bitmaps. I tried to use tag on the bitmap then touchesBegan function. I got a runtime error everytime I touched screen (I think.)

My questions are:
1. Given my requirement, is the method I am using is a good method, or even technically possible?
2. If q#1 answer is no, do you have alternative solution?

Thanks and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an exception inside your `touchesBegan:` function, then your code there has a bug in it.  If you run your app with the debugger, it should tell you on exactly what line of code the problem is occurring.  If I had to guess, I would say that you're trying to send a message to an object which doesn't handle that message, which throws an exception.

Make sure your code is compiling without any warnings -- it's possible you have a typo in a function name somewhere.  If you misspell the message name, it will still compile correctly, but it will throw an exception at runtime when you try to send that message.

Comment: Whoa that was fast, thanks.

I agree with you that there's something wrong with code inside touchesBegan. I was trying to check the tag of dynamically created image to see if I touched the right thing but apparently it doesn't sit well on runtime. I didn't get any syntax error.

Comment: Also I saw another post in this forum about threading between NSTimer and touchesBegan. Is there another way besides threading?